# How to detect video file links in list of different type of urls

Tags: c#, list

I want to create a software that can detect streaming video links,at this point i'm able to grab video links but my software detecting some links which are not video links as shown in picture.

I have used background worker and this code to detect fily type but it is not working
So my problem is that how to filter them in corect way.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
req.Proxy = null;
req.Method = "HEAD";
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)(req.GetResponse());
if(resp.ContentType.IndexOf("video")>0)
{
   list.Add(url);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By extension. There are not so many today for the web.
You can match them using Regex:

```
Regex.IsMatch("inputlink", "\.avi|\.mp4|\.flv|\.wmv"); \\continue the list
```

Comment: what about links not having extensions in them but are video links?ie youtube links